# TF2 stutters with high FPS, low ping

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

I recently acquired a second monitor and installed it with an HDMI cable.  Since then TF2 has been choppy, even though I have high FPS and a low ping.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  My guess is its something to do with the second monitor.  I have a GTX 760 that outputs to both monitors.

Specs: i5-4670k, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7.  That should be everything relevant to this problem.

Comment: Are you running TF2 in fullscreen or windowed mode?

Comment: @Shadur I'm running it in a borderless window.

Comment: If you remove the second monitor from your setup, does the problem persist? If you run it in full screen mode with the second monitor, does the problem persist?

Comment: Are you running with the most up to date video card drivers? Can you provide the rest of your machine spec? cpu, RAM, OS, ect...

Comment: Are you running it across both monitors using SLI, or just one? If just one, are you running on the primary or secondary monitor?

Comment: @Robotnik I'm running on just the primary monitor.  The second monitor is a TV that I only turn on when I need it.  I am using the latest drivers.  I'll edit my post with my specs

Comment: Who said anything about SLI?  If he is using SLI, I would guess that's the issue *(microstuttering is pretty common with SLI)*.

Comment: I'm not on SLI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try turning off the Aero theme and seeing if your performance improves.**

A somewhat common issue with some NVidia video cards on Windows 7 with multiple monitors is that the Aero theme can cause display lag/stuttering.

**Guide for turning off the Aero theme:**

1. Start Button > Control Panel > Personalization
2. Select any of the themes in the Basic And High Contrast Themes category.

**Visual guide for turning off the Aero theme:** (scroll down to the Windows 7 section) http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-aero-on-windows-vista/

Comment: I toggled it on and off and now it's working fine.  Huh

Comment: @sommerjj Glad to hear that it worked.

Comment: @sommerjj If that's the answer who helped you, don't forget to accept it ^_-